# Is ReactJS a controller + a view/presenter in MV*?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, mvvm, reactjs, mvp

On the [ReactJS official site](https://facebook.github.io/react/), I saw this:

> Lots of people use React as the V in MVC. Since React makes no
>   assumptions about the rest of your technology stack, it's easy to try
>   it out on a small feature in an existing project.

And there is demo snippets below the text:

```
var MarkdownEditor = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {value: 'Type some *markdown* here!'};
  },
  handleChange: function() {
    this.setState({value: this.refs.textarea.value});
  },
  rawMarkup: function() {
    return { __html: marked(this.state.value, {sanitize: true}) };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="MarkdownEditor">
        <h3>Input</h3>
        <textarea
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          ref="textarea"
          defaultValue={this.state.value} />
        <h3>Output</h3>
        <div
          className="content"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={this.rawMarkup()}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<MarkdownEditor />, mountNode);
```

The snippet looks like a View **plus** a Controller, which is a bit similar to the BackboneJS way.

Is it true ReactJS is not only a View but also a Controller? Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: no React is just for View purpose. to render a dom into browser that's the job of react

Comment: @DhavalPatel Yes, but add event listeners to process triggered event and do the operations according to the input event is the job of Controller

Comment: With React I think we need to reevaluate what a View is exactly and also discard the entire idea that MVC even applies to React. What a React component does is be responsible of itself and, sometimes, its children. Therefore setting up listeners and trigger events and reacting to input would be a React components main task.

Comment: I always think of react components as the View+Controllers, where the JSX inside (with css) are the views. Rendering child (controller) components, setting up and handling listeners, firing actions to update the model etc etc are all controller-like react functions. I guess the quote is applicable to so-called 'pure' react-components (which do not have state, and whose only job is to render stuff based on props).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does React require jsdom for testing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251990/why-does-react-require-jsdom-for-testing)

Comment: "discard the entire idea that MVC even applies to React". MVC = server side. MVP = browser side. Either MVC or MVP should always be used. There is no question using either is applicable. Cannot afford to discard that idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should React lifecycle methods be implemented in container components or presentation components?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141980/should-react-lifecycle-methods-be-implemented-in-container-components-or-present)