# Should React lifecycle methods be implemented in container components or presentation components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux

I'm attempting to implement [container components](https://medium.com/@learnreact/container-components-c0e67432e005#.3dxvn9hoh) in React and Redux, and I'm unsure of what should take responsibility for lifecycle methods; containers or presentational components. One could argue that the lifecycle methods are presentational as they control DOM updates, but in that respect, aren't they also behavioural?

Furthermore, all of the implementations of container components that I've seen thus far utilise the [`react-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) bindings, as do my own. Even if I keep the concerns clearly separated, is it appropriate to inherit from `React.Component` in the case of a behaviour component?

For example, the app on which I'm working has a `Tab` presentational component, with a `shouldComponentUpdate` method:

```
class Tabs extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        const { activeTab } = this.props;
        return activeTab !== nextProps.activeTab;
    }

    [...]
}
```

On the one hand, this seems like a presentational concern as it controls when component should re-render. On the other hand, however, this is a means of handling when the user clicks a new tab, updating the application's state via an action, thus I'd class this as behavioural.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data should be controlled as close to the root of the tree as possible.  Doing this provides some simple optimizations, being that you're only passing what you need.

This will bubble down to where you are controlling some lifecycle components.  As mgmcdermott mentioned, a lot of lifecycle components really depend on what you're doing, but the best case scenario is to have the simplest, dumbest components.

In most of my projects, in my react directory, I have `components/` and `views/`.  It is always my preference that a view should do as much of the grunt work as possible.  That being said, there a a number of components that I've built that use lifecycle methods like `componentDidMount`, `componentWillMount`, `componentWillUnmount`, but I typically try and isolate updates in my views, since one of their jobs, in my opinion, is controlling data flow.  That means `componentShouldUpdate` would live there.  Personally, I think `componentShouldUpdate` is purely end-of-the-line optimization, though, and I only use it in cases where I'm having large performance issues during a re-render.

I'm not super sure I understand your "inherit from `React.Component`" question.  If you're asking whether or not to use pure functions, es6 `class`, or `React.createClass`, I don't know that there is a standard rule, but it is good to be consistent.

To address whether or not you are dealing with a behaviour or presentation, behaviour is the click, but re-drawing is presentation.  Your behaviour might be well off to exist in your `Tab` component, where the re-draw in your `Tabs` view.  `Tabs` view passes your method from redux to set the currently active tab into your individual `Tab` components, and can then send the behaviour of tab switching through redux so you can do your presentation `componentShouldUpdate`.  Does that make sense?

So your `mapToDispatch` method in your container will have a function to set your active tab, let's call it `activateTab(idx)`, which takes a 0-based index of the tab.  Your container passes that to the containing component that you control, which is `views/Tabs`, and it passes that method along to `components/Tab`.  `components/Tab` will have an `onClick` method which is listening on one of your DOM elements, which then calls `this.props.activateTab(myIndex)` (you could also pass a bound version of activateTab into `components/Tab` so it does not have to be aware of it's own index), which triggers redux, then passes back your data into `views/Tabs` which can handle a `componentShouldUpdate` based on the data from redux.

**Expanded Edit:** Since this was marked as accepted, I'll blow out my code example into something usable to the average person.

As a quick aside, I'm not going to write much redux, as this can be very app dependent, but I'm assuming that you have a state with `activeTabIdx` hanging off the parent.

**containers/TabExample.jsx**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import Tabs from 'views/Tabs.js'

const mapStateToProps = function (state) {
  return {
    activeTabIdx: state.activeTabIdx
    // And whatever else you have...
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = function (dispatch) {
  return {
    activateTab: function (idx) {
      dispatch({
        action: 'ACTIVATE_TAB_IDX',
        idx: idx
      }) // You probably want this in a separate actions/tabs.js file...
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Tabs)
```

**views/Tabs.js**

```
import React, { createClass } from 'react'
import Tab from 'components/Tab.js'

const { number, func } = React.PropTypes

// Alternatively, you can use es6 classes...
export default createClass({
  propTypes: {
    activeTabIdx: number.isRequired,
    activateTab: func.isRequired
  },

  render () {
    const { activeTabIdx } = this.props
    const tabs = ['Tab 1', 'Tab 2', 'Tab 3']

    return (
      <div className='view__tabs'>
        <ol className='tabs'>
          {this.renderTabLinks(tabs, activeTabIdx)}
        </ol>
      </div>
    )
  },

  renderTabLinks (tabs, activeTabIdx) {
    return tabs.map((tab, idx) => {
      return (
        <Tab
          onClick={this.props.activateTabIdx.bind(this, idx)}
          isActive={idx === activeTabIdx}
        >
          {tab}
        </Tab>
      )
    })
  }
})
```

**components/Tab.js**

```
import React, { createClass } from 'react'

const { func, bool } = React.PropTypes

// Alternatively, you can use es6 classes...
export default createClass({
  propTypes: {
    children: node.isRequired,
    onClick: func.isRequired,
    isActive: bool.isRequired
  },

  handleClick (e) {
    const { isActive, onClick } = this.props

    e.preventDefault()

    if (!isActive) {
      onClick()
    }
  },

  render () {
    const { children, isActive } = this.props

    const tabClass = isActive
      ? 'tabs__items tabs__items--active'
      : 'tabs__items'

    return (
      <li className={tabClass}>
        <a className='tabs__item-link' onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {children}
        </a>
      </li>
     )
   }
```

That will mostly do the right thing.  Keep in mind that this doesn't handle/care about tab content, and as a result, you may want to structure your view differently.

Comment: From my expanded example, if you have many **views/Tabs** instances on a page, you have two options.  If you don't care much about the active tab being shared, you *can* use a local state.  You lose some benefits from redux doing this.  Alternatively, you can have a more robust redux state describing a set of activeTabIdx instances for each tab set.

Answer (score 4):

I think that this is a matter of opinion. I personally like to keep my presentational components as dumb as possible. This allows me to also write most of my presentational components as [stateless functions](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions), which are being optimized more and more in React updates. This means that if I can help it, I will prevent any presentational component from having an internal state.

In the case of your example, I don't believe that it is a presentational concern because `componentShouldUpdate` is a pure function of the props, which should be passed whenever this component is used. Even though this component updates the application's state, I believe that because it has no internal state, it is not necessarily behavioral.

Again, I don't think there is really a right or wrong way of doing things here. It reminds me of the discussion about [whether or not Redux should handle all application state](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/482gvg/reactredux_only_keeping_state_in_redux_or_also/). I think if you keep the idea of making presentational components as dumb (reusable) as possible, you can figure out the correct place to put lifecycle methods in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very correct.

Simple act of using a lifecycle method doesn't define the component as a *presentational* or a *container* component.

Lifecycle methods are exactly that — the hooks for your convenience where you can do pretty much anything you want.

A **container component** *typically* does some setup that connects itself to your application's data flow in those lifecycle methods. That's what makes it a container component, not the bare fact that it uses *some* lifecycle methods.

**Presentational components** are *typically* dumb and stateless, therefore they typically don't need those lifecycle methods hooked into. This doesn't mean that it's always the case. A presentational component may be stateful (although this is often undesired) and a stateless component may make use of the lifecycle methods, but in a totally different fashion than a container component would. It might add some event listeners to the document or adjust the cursor position of an input in a totally stateless way.

And perhaps you're mixing up **container** components and **stateful** components. Those are different things, and while container components are stateful, stateful components don't necessarily acts as container components.

Comment: I know what makes it a container component given such a high-level description, but I think I was perhaps seeing some _overlap_ between stateful and container components.

Comment: Perhaps. It might be useful to think that a "container" component does something similar to what a "Controller" does in the MVC pattern. It's not exactly the same behavior, but pretty close. Whereas a "stateful" component is simply a component that holds some state.